# Removing $\cos \theta$ from the given equation?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, area

I have been stuck on a particular question. The question relates to the area of a triangle being equal to the area of a sector. As such, I came to the conclusion that $\sin\frac{\theta}{2} * \cos\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{1}{2}*\theta $ . But I do not quite understand what to do next! Is there some concept to apply here, or did I simply mess up?

($\theta$ is in radians)

Comment: Maybe use that $\sin(2x) = 2 \sin x \cos x$ to simplify.

Comment: Is your angle small? If yes, then $\sin\theta\approx\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the identity:$$\sin\big(\frac{\theta}{2}\big)\cos\big(\frac{\theta}{2}\big)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(\theta)$$ to remove the cosine. Then set $$\frac{1}{2}\sin(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\theta$$. Now it is much simpler. Can you finish?

Comment: Quite so, yes! This seems to be simple, yet helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the equation is equivalent to

$$\sin \theta =\theta$$

whose solution is $\theta =0$.

Comment: Hm.... but if $\theta = 0$ then doesnt that mean that the whole equation goes to zero?

Comment: @M4t1-1 - The equation itself is legitimate. It happens to have its root equal to 0, just as the equation $x=x^2$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The area of the triangle equals $\sin \frac \theta2 \cos \frac \theta2 = \frac 12 \sin \theta$  The area of the section of the circle is $\frac \theta 2$

From this geometric argument we can conclude that $|\sin \theta |\le |\theta|$ but when $\theta$ is small they are nearly equal.